# AWS S3 hidden flag lost after uploading files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload, hidden

I am having a problem with uploading hidden files to s3 and getting them back.

Basically, I upload the hidden files to s3 and download them back. The files become visible (hidden checkbox is unchecked).

Btw, this is Windows.

Is there anything I am missing out or this is the way it's supposed to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hidden flag is a Windows file system thing. S3 isn't a Windows filesystem, so when you upload a file to S3, it can't retain that Windows-specific flag. I think you would have to write some custom code to set extra, custom metadata on the S3 objects if they were marked as hidden in Windows, and custom download code to check for that metadata and mark the files as hidden if they are being downloaded onto a Windows machine.

There might be some specific S3 applications for Windows that would manage this. What tool are you using right now to upload to S3?

Comment: I am using the .Net sdk, I think I might just have to add some custom metadata. Thanks for your answer.